# how does php's session work? what encryption method does it use

Tags: php, session

here is an example of what i'm wondering from.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = "mike";
    $_SESSION['lname'] = "donwell";
    $_SESSION['address'] = "111 north welding ave.";

    print $_SESSION['name'] . "<br/>";
    print $_SESSION['lname']. "<br/>";
    print $_SESSION['address']. "<br/>";

?>
```

when i run this on a browser and view cookies i see a PHPSESSID cookie whose value is always random.
what encryption method is it using to generate the value that is displayed.

also for security purposes of myself are people able to view sessions on my site and its values? since its always encrypted?

thanks

Comment: are you asking for the random string generator for the PHPSESSID?  by default session data is not encrypted since the data resides on the server and normally does not need to be encrypted for security.  the only way for a user to view session data is if you send that data to the user (it's almost the exact opposite for cookies)

Answer (score 5):

Sessions are not encrypted by default. The data is just stored in serialised form in temporary directory on server's hard disk. This can be changed by [redefining session handling functions](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

You can for example use database to store session data, as well as encrypt it.

THe PHPSESSID value you see, is just an MD5 identifier of session file assigned to current browser session.

Answer (score 0):

Your session-data is not encrypted. This ominous string is just something very random hashed, maybe MD5-hashing (see MD5()-function), but it has no meaning and there would be no reason trying to decrypt it. and sessions are private, so nobody can see it except for the visitor and the site-admin. But if somebody steels through network-sniffing or a troyan on your PC the session-key, then he can given the propper setup authenticate as you ... that's called session-hijacking.

Best

Raffael

Answer (score 0):

The raw session data is not public. By default, php will write session data to a path outside of your doc root/htdocs. The session save path can be set in php.ini (session.save_path). The user can only access session data associated with their session id (by default, its stored in a cookie).

I don't believe php encrypts the session data before saving it (its just serialized). IMO, you should use a custom session handler. You'll have much greater control over where the data is stored, how it is encoded, and accessed (eg, via unique id in cookie). Many frameworks include a custom session handler (Kohana 3 has a nice one ;) ).

Doc on using custom session handler: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Edit: Updated based on Mchl's comment

Comment: By default it's serialized only. No base64 encoding. If you have access to webserver's temporary directory, you can look into session files with plain text editor.